# Submitting text with blessed.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, blessed

I'm trying to write a function that would create a `textarea` element to read a string and remove the element after it's done.
Here's what I ended up with:

```js
function getText() {
  let input = blessed.textarea({
    parent: screen,
    top: 'center',
    left: 'center',
    width: '50%',
    height: '25%',
    border: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    inputOnFocus: true,
    style: {
      border: {
        fg: 'default'
      }
    }
  });
  input.key(['enter'], () => input.submit());
  input.key(['escape'], () => input.cancel());
  input.on('submit', () => {
    let text = input.getValue();
    input.destroy();
    // process the text... 
    debug('done!');
  });
  input.on('cancel', () => {
    input.destroy();
    debug('cancelled');
  });
  input.focus();
}
```

However, whenever I press 'enter' it cancels the input rather than submits it. I've tried debugging the code and I found out that although the right handler is called for the key event, a `cancel` handler is called afterwards. Could anyone tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong?

### Edit

After having a look at the source code of the `textarea` I found out that `submit()` and `cancel()` methods basically do the same thing:

```
Textarea.prototype.submit = function() {
  if (!this.__listener) return;
  return this.__listener('\x1b', { name: 'escape' });
};

Textarea.prototype.cancel = function() {
  if (!this.__listener) return;
  return this.__listener('\x1b', { name: 'escape' });
};
```

Calling `__listener()` here in fact calls `_listener` due to the tethering done beforehand. Since the `key.name` is equal to `'escape'`, inside the method occurs a call to `done(null, null)`. Inside `done()` among other operations we emit `submit` or `cancel` event based on the second argument of the call, `value`. Here's the corresponding snippet of code:

```
if (err) {
  self.emit('error', err);
} else if (value != null) {
  self.emit('submit', value);
} else {
  self.emit('cancel', value);
}
self.emit('action', value);
```

I might be missing something, but if not, all that means that both `submit()` and `cancel()` methods of the element in fact emit a `cancel` event.

Comment: seems like you `destroy` it once `submit` event occurs then process the text.

Comment: @Chay22 I doubt that the problem since being a simple type a string is copied whenever assignment occurs. However, I noticed some odd things in the source code of the library, so I'll edit the question.

Comment: I see. That must be a bug, and you have likely to call `_done` yourself. `input.key(['enter'], () => input._done(null, input.getValue()))`. It's better to open an issue on their github.

Comment: @Chay22 will do that, thank you! :)